# Radial electric field of radial polarizable material

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I'm given a radial charge distribution $\rho(r)$ of a material with a radial polarization density. The density is given by either (1) $P(r)\propto r^n$ or (2) $P(r)\propto E(r)$, all in the radial direction $\hat{r}$. I now want to calculate the electric field $E(r)$ this radial charge distribution generates. Without polarization, this is easily done using
$$E(r)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0r^2}\int_{r'\leq r}\mathrm{d}r'\,r'{}^2\rho(r')$$
which follows from Gauss's law. But how is polarization dealt with in this case, so how does the electric field look like in that case? Most answers/sources I could find on this topic are about spheres inside some electric field not the sphere creating the electric field.

Edit: So from what I understand, I need the displacement field $D(r)=\varepsilon_0E(r)+P(r)$ with the property $\nabla\cdot D(r)=\rho(r)=\varepsilon_0\nabla\cdot E(r)+\nabla\cdot P(r)$. This implies, for the polarization density given by just a function, I can write the electric field as
$$E(r)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0r^2}\int_{r'\leq r}\mathrm{d}r'\,r'{}^2\Bigl(\rho(r')-\frac{1}{r'{}^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r'}(r'{}^2P(r'))\Bigr).$$
Is this correct? (In the case $P\propto E$ you can just factor the electric field out)

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite easy, if you know the constitutive law linking the dispalcement field $\mathbf{d}$, $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{p}$.

Being $\mathbf{d} = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{p}$, if the behavior of the medium is linear and isotropic, the displacement field can be written using the relative permittivity $\varepsilon_r$ as $\mathbf{d} = \varepsilon \mathbf{e} = \varepsilon_r \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} $, so that you can write

$\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{d} - \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} = \varepsilon_0 \left( \varepsilon_r - 1\right) \mathbf{e}  = \varepsilon_0 \chi \mathbf{e}$,

being $\chi$ the electric susceptibility.